# How to change an user status in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def active_for_authentication?<br>
    super and self.is_active?<br>
end
```

I have this method in my `User.rb`, which basically allows me to block any inactive user or non-admin to log in and it is working very well.

But now I want to create a method to allow my admin to activate and deactivate any user from my view. I have already listed all my users and their respective status (active or not) in a view. Now when I click the button it should change the user to active if it is inactive and inactive if it is active!

Comment: Hope this is  the one you are looking for https://blog.kodius.io/how-to-deactivate-user-rails-with-devise

Comment: Thanks, it is basically what I have but my struggle is how to integrate it in my view, like when I click a button it deactivates the user and when I click again it activates back, in my controller I have def change_status
    if @users.status == true 
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
end and in my view <% if user.is_active?%>
          <%= user.name%> <%= button_to "Desactivar", change_status_path%>
          <% else %>
            <%= user.name%> <%= button_to "Activar", change_status_path%>
          <% end %> but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method in the controller

```rb
def change_status
  if @users.status?
    @users.update_attribute(:status, false)
  else
    @users.update_attribute(:status, true)
  end 
end
```

Comment: For some reason, that's the answer I'm getting back --- undefined method `status?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That is because the @users variable in your case is nil, that is, you are not looking for the user you are going to change the status before

Comment: Could you help me with that? I just started programming in rails

Comment: You need to send in your view
```ruby
<% if user.is_active?%>
<%= user.name%> <%= button_to "Desactivar", change_status_path(user)%> <% else %>
<%= user.name%> <%= button_to "Activar", change_status_path(user)%>
<% end %>
```
You must also correct the route so that it checks by parameter the: id
Then in your controller

```ruby
def change_status
# get this user
@user = UserModel.find(:id)
  if @user.status?
    @user.update_attribute(:status, false)
  else
    @user.update_attribute(:status, true)
  end 
end
```